# Removing and logging a file at the same time in unix

Tags: unix

I want to search the files in certain folders and sub folders and then remove it from the same and then move it to some log directory?
I can use two find command for the same and get the work done like below

```
find $Some_Path -name "*_.txt" -type f  >> $SOMELOGDIR

find $Some_Path -name "*_.txt" -type f -exec rm -rf '{}' ';'
```

Can we get the work done using a single find command?

Comment: I do not understand that how does `find ... >> $SOMELOGDIR` this works (move it to some log directory) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use can use `-print` / `-printf` options for the `find` command along with `-exec` or `-delete`. See manual pages.

Also `rm -v ...` will print what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

> search the files in certain folders and sub folders and then remove it
>   from the same and then move it to some log directory

You can try this `find`:

```
find . -name '*_.txt' -type f -exec mv '{}' $LOGDIR \;
```

Comment: This will just move the file to the log directory, what about removing the files after logging the data